# Coverity: the build capture percentage is undesirably 0%

Tags: c, static-code-analysis, coverity

I using Coverity to analyze code C.

**config command:**

> cov-configure --compiler /opt/toolchains/stbgcc-4.5.4-2.9/bin/mipsel-linux-uclibc-gcc --comptype gcc --config /opt/cov-analysis-linux64-7.5.1/config/coverity_config.xml

And configuration step is successfully.

**Build command:**

> cov-build --dir ../platform/drivers --record-only --encoding EUC-KR sudo make platform FORCE=1

When coverity build had finished,
i saw in build-log: The cov-build utility completed successfully.
And the warning in pop up block:

> the build capture percentage is undesirably 0%

[image: error]

Then i still analyze data:

**Analyze command:**

> cov-analyze --user-model-file >~/work/CoverityData/stdioUserModel.xmldb --parse-warnings-config >~/work/CoverityData/parse_warnings.conf --dir ../platform/drivers/ >--all --checker-option NO_EFFECT:extra_comma:0 -j 4

and i got error:

> Error: intermediate directory contains no translation units.

I guess the warning in build-step made the error in analysis step.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: By contacting support@coverity.com? BTW is your code C *and* java? With the lack of any code or background information, how do you expect anyone to wave a magic wand for you?

Comment: A good first start to find out why is to check the build log. Did your build actually do anything? Were your compilers configured correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be with the `--record-only` portion of your `cov-build` invocation - that captures the compiler invocations, but doesn't actually emit them. Try removing that and try again. Alternatively, you could use `cov-build --replay -j X` to replay those compilations; some caveats apply, it's usually best to capture the compilations directly.

Please note that using `sudo` in your build command is exceptionally dangerous and should be avoided. Is it really necessary?

Comment: Hi Caleb. Sorry to waste your time. You'r right. I made a mistake when copy/paste the build command. I fixed the build command on above question. Please review and give me any idea.

Comment: I've updated my answer, however it's an educated guess - I'd need the build log to be able to determine with certainty whether that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check in the build_log file, located in ../platform/drivers/.
Look for lines containing [ERROR] - there may be errors locating header files etc.

Another possibility is to perform a test build first - this might only be possible from the IDE - to ensure that the build is being invoked correctly